# Disable cursorline when leaving NERD tree window

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I want to disable `cursorline` when leaving the NERD tree window and enable it when entering the window again.

The following setting works fine when using `<C-w>w` or similar, but not when `<CR>`. Hitting `<CR>` opens the file in other window, moves to it, and `cursorline` remains visible. How can I make it work?

```
augroup Cursorline
  au!
  au WinEnter * if exists('t:NERDTreeBufName') && bufname("%") == t:NERDTreeBufName | setlocal cursorline | endif
  au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
```

Environment:

```
- vim
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 14 2017 20:07:29)
Included patches: 1-1297
- NERDTree
master (461ea6d2d854100f7954c21453bb3b926ad930e6)
- OS
Linux
- Terminal
mintty on Windows
GNU screen
TERM=screen-256color-bce
```

.vimrc (simplified for testing):

```
set nocompatible
syntax enable

set runtimepath^=~/git/nerdtree/

autocmd! BufEnter * call ToggleCursorLine()

function! ToggleCursorLine()
  if (bufname("%") =~ "NERD_Tree_")
    setlocal cursorline
  else
    setlocal nocursorline
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for all window panes not just the NERDTree pane.
These lines go above in your .vimrc.

```
set cursorline 
set cursorcolumn
```

These lines go below in your .vimrc.

```
augroup cursor_off
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinLeave * set nocursorline nocursorcolumn
    autocmd WinEnter * set cursorline cursorcolumn
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to enable in NERDTree window, disable in other windows. Your solution makes cursorline always enabled in the active window.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have this functionality, please but the following code in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd! BufEnter * call ToggleCursorLine()

function! ToggleCursorLine()
    if (bufname("%") =~ "NERD_Tree_")
        setlocal cursorline
    else
        setlocal nocursorline
    endif
endfunction
```

This creates a function, that will be executed via autocommand on entering any buffer and set cursorline accordingly.
Tested on Mac with vim 8.0.237 in iterm 3.1.5.b2.

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work. `cursorline` is still highlighted in the NERD tree window after leaving it with `<CR>`. I'm starting to think that I need to modify NERD tree code.

Comment: Are you setting `cursorline` in the `.vimrc`? What OS/terminal/vim are you using? And you need to delete what you are using now...

Comment: bufname('#') =~ 'NERD_tree_\d\+', with this if condition this function works.